# System clock offsetting from HW clock on boot

Tags: arch-linux, clock

I recently did a full update to my Arch Linux system and now, for some reason, the system clock is being set to an offset of +5 hours on boot, compared to the HW clock. I am in US EST (UTC-5). When I boot, the HW clock seems to be correct; however, the system clock is advanced by 5 hours:

```
# date
Sun Feb  4 12:07:01 AM EST 2024
# hwclock --show
2024-02-03 19:07:07.691763-05:00
```

If I go into the Mate Desktop settings and correct the system time to where it should be, it doesn't persist - the next time I boot I again have the situation above, where the system clock is advanced by 5 hours.

The 5-hour offset suggests there may be an issue with my timezone settings - that the system clock is not aware of the correct time zone (although the `date` output above states 'EST'?). Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Please note that I am using Arch Linux with OpenRC (*not* systemd) and I am not currently using NTP.

**Edit:**

Adding output of `hwclock -v`. As far as I can see, all of this looks correct. So, the problem appears to be an issue with setting the system clock from the HW clock on boot. Perhaps the system is assuming the HW clock is in local time, rather than UTC (which would explain the 5 hour offset)? However, I'm not sure why it would be doing that, or where that setting would be.

```
# hwclock -v
hwclock from util-linux 2.37.2
System Time: 1707100379.710788
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Using the rtc interface to the clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1707004842 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1707004842 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on UTC time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2024/02/04 21:33:01
Hw clock time : 2024/02/04 21:33:01 = 1707082381 seconds since 1969
Time since last adjustment is 77539 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
2024-02-04 16:33:00.624087-05:00
```

Comment: Were you in Windows? Windows sets the hardware clock to local time, while Linux keeps the clock in UTC and uses timezones (the `$TZ` environment variable). `man hwclock` will show you how to fix it.

Comment: @waltinator I had a Windows/Linux dual boot on this desktop PC previously; however, I nuked the Windows system several years ago. I'm not sure why doing an Arch update a few days ago would have affected the hwclock, but I will check `man hwclock` and see if it can help. Thanks!

Comment: Added the output of `hwclock -v` above.

Comment: The Arch update most likely updated `timezone-data` . Package: [tzdata](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/tzdata/) which may have removed `/etc/localtime/`, which would expose the issue.

Comment: The 7 hour difference is quite odd. I'd recommend to check out the output of "timedatectl" on a systemd-based distribution.

Comment: @AlexK973 it's a 5-hour difference. The output of `date`is just after midnight the next day (advanced by 5 hours from 19:07 pm).

Answer (score 1):

There may be a startup script that is setting your HW clock to UTC. You would need to search for it within your OS.

You can use `hwclock` to set the host to use your local time zone via:

`hwclock --localtime && hwclock --systohc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the `hwclock` output says '-05:00' at the end, so as far as I can see, both hwclock and the system clock seem to know I am on UTC-5? Also, if the hwclock was set to UTC and the system clock was recognizing the correct timezone, wouldn't the system clock be *behind* the hwclock (rather than the other way around)? I must admit I am confused though ...

Comment: The --systohc flag will reset the hwclock to match your system/OS, completing the process.

Comment: I added the output of `hwclock -v` to my post, which confirms that the HW clock is indeed using UTC. However, I don't understand why that would cause a problem. `man hwclock` seems to suggest that UTC for the hardware clock is default and preferred in Linux: 'POSIX systems, like Linux, are designed to have the System Clock operate in the UTC timescale. The Hardware Clock’s purpose is to initialize the System Clock, so also keeping it in UTC makes sense.'

Comment: @Time4Tea: See my Answer.  Alan's answer is correct (His answer is my option 1).  The reason `hwclock` knows your offset is 5 Hours is because `/etc/localtime` is symlinked to a timezone.  In order to fix it the way I believe you want (see option 2) is to set the system clock to UTC and then let the OS compute the timezone by looking at the `/etc/localtime` link and adding or subtracting appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Is the last change timestamp of `/etc/localtime` newer than the timestamp of your current initramfs file?

If so, your initramfs file still holds the old timezones setting and it gets used in the earliest stage of the boot... during which time the system clock is set from the battery-backed Real-Time Clock module.

Once the real root filesystem gets mounted, the system will see the correct `/etc/localtime`, but by then it will be too late: the system clock is already set.

I'm not too familiar with Arch, but I believe `mkinitcpio` might be the command to use in refreshing your initramfs file.

Also, whenever you use `hwclock` to adjust the hardware clock, it will update the third line of `/etc/adjtime` to indicate whether the hardware clock is in local time or in UTC. If the initramfs version of `/etc/adjtime` is out of sync with the one in your real root filesystem, that could cause the system time to gain an offset too.

Comment: Thanks, however I checked this and the initramfs file is newer. So, I don't think that can be the reason. Was a good idea though!

Answer (score 1):

### Set Your System/BIOS Clock to Desired Time Zone

If you still had Windows, I would recommend this registry modification:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

The above registry setting tells Windows that your system time is set in UTC, which you may have already applied from seeing your verbose `hwclock` output.

To fix this now that you've removed Windows, we have 2 options:

1. Inform `hwclock` that the time is stored as localtime (which Alan has done, until I reread the comments).
2. Set the system clock and date manually to UTC, and then inform `hwclock` again.

---

### Option 1

1. Access your BIOS/UEFI Firmware, and set the time and date to your local time.
2. Log back in and from a terminal: `hwclock --systohc --localtime`

### Option 2

This would be the easiest for you, due to the fact that the time is stored as UTC already (per your output, though I cant be sure):

1. Access your BIOS/UEFI Firmware, and set the time and date to UTC (which `hwclock -v` confirms is already done)
2. Log back in and from a terminal issue: `hwclock --utc`

   - For an added check: `hwclock --systohc --utc`
3. Verify your correct timezone is still set: `ls -l /etc/localtime`

If everything worked right (option 2), the OS will now compute the Timezone Offset, and display the time in your timezone, and the System will store the time in UTC.

### Optional

Install the [Network Time Protocol Daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon)

---

### In Response To Comments

1. RE: Windows

   - I entered my Freshman year in Junior College around 1996, in between the adoption Window from [Windows 3.1](https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-3/31) to [Windows 95](https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-95/osr-2) (I provided links with screenshots because due to the passage of time , and that thing we call death there won't be people like me to remember).
   - In 1996 the majority of PC users, only used their computers for *Personal* tasks such as (There was no widely adopted internet usage):

     1. Gaming - Which was more like a souped up 8-bit Nintendo Game.  See [Prince of Persia | 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game)). Take a look at the Ports Section.
     2. Writing Documents in programs like [WordPerfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPerfect). The DOS version was the favorite amongst Windows 3.1 users. Side Note: Word Perfect is still around today as a main competitor to MS Office
2. RE: Hardware Clock

   - While there were other uses, I did not list, note that I did not include anything that had to do with the Internet or networking, because Windows first design never had any networking built in.  The networking stack in Windows is actually an add in component.  See Windows 3.11 in the link above. Because of this, and because Windows was sold to everyone everywhere, the developers chose to store the time and date relative to the time zone people lived in in the [CMOS Battery](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025368/processors.html), a.k.a. local time.
   - The Linux Kernel was built with the networking components built-in versus Windows that had them added as an extra component. [UTC or Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) has been around since 1963 starting with it's use by the military to coordinate communication between units, or vehicles like submarines.

UTC was chosen in Linux as the default time mechanism, mainly because of Linux's uses in servers.  The only way for a server in the USA and a server either in the USA or anywhere else in the world to communicate and log properly between them is to ignore the time zone. As such, that default is UTC.

- The Hardware Clock, a.k.a. the CMOS battery needs adjustment because unless reset by the Registry Hack above, Windows still stores the time in the battery as Local Time, regardless of the version, and to maintain backward compatibility.  That was true before you did the Arch update, but `/etc/localtime` was symlinked to the proper time zone from the `tzdata` package, and `hwclock` is probably using `--localtime`. This is only speculation on my part, but if `tzdata` was updated, the symlink to`/etc/localtime` was removed/replaced during the update.  If deleted, the time zone would revert back to UTC.  Because the time is stored as local, *even though Windows is nuked*, and the symlink is now missing, Arch is computing the time differently and the result you see is the 7-hour difference between time zones (UTC+0 plus or minus UTC-7).

**There is now a 7 hour difference between the time stored in your battery, and the time computed** by Arch because Arch looks at the time zone config that now mistakenly returns UTC, Arch then asks `hwclock` for the system time, which is returned and computed as UTC.  Arch then computes the offset for the time zone because `hwclock` is still set to localtime(to account for Windows).  MATE's localization settings are configured to add 5 hours to account for the Eastern Time Zone , or 7 for Mountain Standard Time.

In case you didn't peruse the UTC link, [study this photo of current time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#/media/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png).  If you aren't in the time zone for Eastern Standard Time (19 - 12 = 7 which would put you in MST - Mountain Standard Time, New Mexico Colorado etc, per AlexK's comment something is odd here, because the offset should be 17 - 12 = 5 for EST: If you subtract the time given by `hwclock` from the time given by the `date` command, the difference gives you the offset value), use the picture to determine what time zone you should be in and adjust accordingly.

To adjust:

1. Set the `hwclock` to UTC, and reboot - See Option 2.2
2. Determine what the actual values for the time and date are that are stored in the CMOS battery by going to your PC's settings utility (I have a hunch it's your local time - per your output, `hwlock` is reporting `Time read from Hardware Clock: 2024/02/04 21:33:01`, and per your answer to Alan's comment, the output does confirm "just after 9:30", which is your local time, and confirms my hunch).
3. [Set the time manually if needed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide#Time), as close as you can to the current UTC time and date (because Linux prefers UTC, and Windows is gone), and reboot

   - Read all of Section 3.3 in the above link, the line about UTC, and the line about NTP are the reason you're having issues, and wrote your post
4. Install the NTP daemon - See Optional

   - Add the service to the default run level so that the time is sync'ed every reboot/restart.
5. Recreate the `/etc/localtime` symlink (using the time zone needed from the picture), now that both the `hwclock` and the NTP daemon are installed and set properly

If the adjustment goes well, MATE will display your local time which will be correct, but the time will now be stored as UTC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however I have similar questions/confusion as with Allan's. There are 2 key points I don't understand. 1) I don't see why Window being installed on the machine previously should affect anything. I removed Windows over 4 years ago and the clocks were fine until I did an Arch update within the past 2 weeks.

Comment: 2) I don't understand why it is the hardware clock that needs fixing. As far as I can see, the hardware clock is correct. So, doesn't that suggest the issue is with the Linux system misinterpreting the hardware clock when setting the system time? I don't mean to be difficult, but would just like to understand these things.

Comment: @Time4Tea See Response Section.  Note that this is based on experience, as in the early 90's I upgraded plenty of paying customers from Windows 3.1 to Windows 95.  I also found [this](https://malwaretips.com/threads/fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting.126258/) as the only link to support it.  I wanted to be as thorough as possible so it's lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps the system is assuming the HW clock is in local time, rather
> than UTC (which would explain the 5 hour offset)? However, I'm not
> sure why it would be doing that, or where that setting would be.

Sounds reasonable. The question is: why?

On Gentoo, when using OpenRC, there is an init script called `hwclock`. This can be added to the boot services, and then it will handle setting up the system clock at startup from the RTC and also writing back the system clock at shutdown to the RTC.

This init script has a configuration file in `/etc/conf.d/hwclock`, which contains a few configuration settings:

```
# Set CLOCK to "UTC" if your Hardware Clock is set to UTC (also known as
# Greenwich Mean Time).  If that clock is set to the local time, then
# set CLOCK to "local".  Note that if you dual boot with Windows, then
# you should set it to "local".
clock="UTC"

# If you want the hwclock script to set the system time (software clock)
# to match the current hardware clock during bootup, leave this
# commented out.
# However, you can set this to "NO" if you are running a modern kernel
# and using NTP to synchronize your system clock.
#clock_hctosys="YES"

# If you do not want to set the hardware clock to the current system
# time (software clock) during shutdown, set this to no.
#clock_systohc="YES"

# If you wish to pass any other arguments to hwclock during bootup,
# you may do so here. Alpha users may wish to use --arc or --srm here.
clock_args=""
```

Here the `clock_hctosys` flag controls the boot action (setting up the system clock from the RTC), and the `clock_systohc` flag controls the shutdown action (copying back the system clock to the RTC). And of course the `clock` controls whether the RTC stores time in UTC or local time.

I'm no Arch expert, but I expect that something similar is in operation there as well.

Comment: Bingo! This was the issue. I was unaware of that init script, but the first option was set to "local" and changing it to "UTC" immediately fixed the problem. I guess my Arch system with OpenRC is using similar init scripts to Gentoo. Perhaps that script had been overwritten during the system update. Thanks so much! Giving you the bounty.

Comment: That `/etc/conf.d` folder looks like a useful one to check out, in general.